# C++ Programming Errors: C4703, C4700

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i am relatively new to programming, i just learned c++ and i am getting 2 errors for a HW assignment from school;

Error   2 error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'searchValueptr' used   Line 83
and
Error   3 error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'createdArray' used
Line 70

I cannot for the life of me figure out why or how to fix it can some one help me please.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

// prototypes
int *createArray(int &size);
void findStats(int *arr, int size, int &min, int &max, double &average);
int *searchElement(int *arr, int size, int *element);


int main ()
{
    int choice, size;

    bool menuOn = true;

    while (menuOn == true)
    {
        cout << "1 - Create and initialize a dynamic array.\n";
        cout << "2 - Display statistics on the array.\n";
        cout << "3 - Search for an element.\n";
        cout << "4 - Exit.\n";
        cout << "Enter your choice and press return: ";

        cin >> choice;

        cout << endl;

        switch (choice)
        {

            case 1:
                int *createdArray;
                cout << "Please enter a size for the array: ";
                cin >> size;
                createdArray = createArray(size);

                for (int x=0; x < size; x++)
                {
                    cout << "Value of array at index " << x << ": " << createdArray[x] << endl;
                }

                cout << endl;

                break;

            case 2:
                int minNum;
                int maxNum;
                double avgNum;
                findStats(createdArray, size, minNum, maxNum, avgNum);
                cout << endl << "The maximum number is: " << maxNum;
                cout << endl << "The minimum number is: " << minNum;
                cout << endl << "The average number is: " << avgNum;
                cout << endl << endl;
                break;

            case 3:
                int *searchValueptr;
                int searchValue;
                cout << "Enter a value to search for: ";
                cin >> searchValue;
                *searchValueptr = searchValue;
                searchElement(createdArray, size, searchValueptr);
                break;


            case 4:
                cout << "Thanks for using this program";
                menuOn = false;
                break;

            default:
                cout << "Not a Valid Choice. \n";
                cout << "Choose again.\n";
                cin >> choice;
                break;

        }

    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause"); 
    return 0; 

} // end function main () 

int *createArray(int &size) 
{
    unsigned seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);
    int *randArray = new int [size];
    for (int x=0; x < size; x++)
    {
        randArray[x] = rand();
    }

    cout << endl;
    return randArray;
}

void findStats(int *arr, int size, int &min, int &max, double &average)
{
    min = arr[0];
    max = arr[0];
    double sum = 0;
    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        if (min >= arr[count])
        {
            min = arr[count];
        }

        if (max <= arr[count])
        {
            max = arr[count];
        }
        sum += arr[count];
    }

    average = sum/size;
}

int *searchElement(int *arr, int size, int *element)
{
    bool match = false;
    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        if (arr[count] == *element)
        {
            match = true;         
        }

    }
    if (match)
    {
        cout << "Match Found at: " << element;
        return element;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "No Found";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does MSVC really compile this? Anyway, `searchValueptr` is self-explanatory. Pointers aren't initialized by default and then you dereference it.

Comment: Oh never mind. I mistook my imagined compiler error for the one you'd get if you *initialized* those variables in the cases.

Comment: the compiler is telling you you're using something without ever initializing it first. Its obvious where it is; though it may not be so obvious that without `{ }` block scoping, fixing it will require moving the required initializers (and thus the variables) outside of the switch block. `searchValueptr` isn't needed regardless.

Answer (score 0):

either use

```
searchValueptr = &searchValue;
```

or send the pass the address of searchValue

```
searchElement(createdArray, size, &searchValue);
break;
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU!!!!! any help for error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'createdArray' used ?

Comment: @user3367260 move `createdArray` outside of the switch-case and make it local to `main()`.

Comment: @user3367260, Do note in addition that creating variables in one case of a switch and using them in later cases is extremely uncommon from what I've seen, and I'm not sure I know of any good reasons to ever do that.

Comment: @user3367260 already advised.... consider the case if I directly choose option 2 what will be case...... `createdArray` is not initialized....

Comment: initialize `createdArray` with NULL and in each function add check `if(createdArray==NULL) return;`